# Django Model.objects.all() doesn't give all the objects

Tags: python, django-models, django-views

In my Django model I have 2 field. When I execute below code it just prints the resolution field. How can I get the all fields data in a list?

```
x = ResolutionsModel.objects.all()
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

**models.py**

```
class ResolutionsModel(models.Model):
    resolution = models.TextField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    act_abbreviation = models.TextField(max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.resolution
```

Comment: You are just returning the text of `resolution ` with `return self.resolution`. What *exactly* do you want `print(x)` to do? a list of strings? and object-like notation? Whatever that is, make `__str__()` return that string.

Comment: you're also printing the whole queryset (`x`) for each iteration through the loop. You might have meant `for item in x: print(item)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your model says that to represent an instance of itself as a string it should use the value of `resolution`. So by printing an instance, that's what you're getting - the value of `resolution`.

If you pass your queryset to a template you could output the values from all the fields.

For the purposes of your test in python you'd have to specifically include each field;

```
x = ResolutionsModel.objects.all()
for i in x:
    print(i.resolution)
    print(i.act_abbreviation)
```

If you actually want to get data in a list, you might want to read about how to use `values_list` on a queryset; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

For the purpose of getting to know django you could also adapt your str method;

```
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.resolution}, {self.act_abbreviation}"
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case:

```
x = ResolutionsModel.objects.all()
```

The x here is a query set, which returns a bunch of entries from data base, each entry is a database entry:

```
for i in x:
    print(i)

i # is a database entry, you can access i.resolution & i.act_abbreviation at each loop.
```

In the end, everything is an object.